# REACT - Composition of a component with subcomponents in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, static, composition, subcomponent

react-bootstrap let you create a modal component with:

```
<Modal>
    <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
        <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
        <Button>Close</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

I want to do a composition of the modal component and create a MyModal component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Modal, ModalBody, ModalProps } from 'react-bootstrap';

interface Props extends ModalProps {
  plain?: boolean;
}

class MyModal extends React.Component<Props> {

  static Body: typeof ModalBody;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { plain, ...other } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal className={plain ? 'plain' : ''} {...other} />
    );
  }
}

export default MyModal;
```

but if I use it like this:

```
import MyModal from './MyModal';

...

render() {
  return (
    <MyModal plain={true}>
      <MyModal.Body>
        <p>Hello!</p>
      </MyModal.Body>
    </MyModal>
  );
}
```

I get the following error:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static Body: typeof ModalBody;
```

is `undefined`, so it cannot be used as `<MyModal.Body>`.

In case it's inherited from wrapped component, it should be:

```
static Body = ModalBody;
```

Where `Body` type is inferred.

This problem could be avoided by using TypeScript `strict` (`strictNullChecks`) compiler option.

Comment: `This problem could be avoided by using TypeScript strict (strictNullChecks) compiler option.` Thank god you pointed this out :)